# Constraint are not working with UINavigationBar item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, constraints

I am trying to give leading and trailing space to UISearchbar. I have almost tried everything. Height, width, leading and trailing contraint but nothing works. Please let me know how to apply the constraint as I am loading the navigation bar items programmatically.

```
func setupsearchbar() {
    //  Setup the Search Controller
    searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self as? UISearchResultsUpdating
    searchcontroller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchcontroller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchcontroller.searchBar
    searchcontroller.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchcontroller.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    searchcontroller.searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true


    if let textfield = searchcontroller.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

        textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue

        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 18
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me why my navigation bar is not responding to the Constraint.

Comment: Use it: ´  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()´

Comment: @mohsen no bro this is not working. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you loss this: self.view.clipsToBounds = true

```
backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 18
backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
self.view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Still no effect, I even have tried giving trailing and leading even they are not working.